# Many 1000s of URL redirects in Drupal 7: PathAuto/GlobalRedirect, apache .htaccess, or another solution?

Tags: drupal, scalability, drupal-path-aliases

I am looking for the 'best' (fastest, most efficient) way to map http requests when there could be as many as 30,000 different URLs that need mapping.

I have made a map pointing URLs on the old vBulletin system to the URLs on the new Drupal 7 system.

My question is how to do the rewriting. I cannot use Apache mod_rewrite and RewriteMap since my server admin does not allow it. I prefer not to write a custom module. So I am looking for the best (most scalable) Drupal module or another solution.

I would assume PathAuto and Global Redirect would be the way to go but I want to know if there are scaleability issues with so many URLs in the map.

Apache mod_rewrite's RewriteMap reads the map and stores in memory until the file's mtime is changed -- does Global Redirect do that?

Edit: I do not have access to use Apache's RewriteMap directive, but I could place the redirects in an .htaccess file -- would that be cached in memory, or looked up on each request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no problem with tens of thousands of URL aliases using the modules

Redirect
Global Redirect
PathAuto

I imported the aliases with Redirect Import (but ran into file upload size limit).